# Merge into a BigQuery Partitioned Table via a Join Without Scanning Entire Table

Tags: google-bigquery

Sample scenario..
I have "BigTable" with millions of rows and "TinyTable" with just a few rows. I need to merge some information from TinyTable into BigTable.
BigTable is partitioned by the column "date_time". My merge will join on date_time and ID. 

I really only need the ID column to do the join, but I thought having the date_time column there as well would allow BQ to prune the partitions and look only at the dates necessary. Nope. It does a full scan on BigTable (billing me for Gigabytes of data)... even if TinyTable just has one value (i.e. from one date) in it.

```
BigTable
+---------------------------+---------+-------+
|         date_time         |      ID | value |
+---------------------------+---------+-------+
| '2019-03-13 00:00:00 UTC' |     100 | .2345 |
| '2019-03-13 00:00:00 UTC' |     101 |   .65 |
| '2019-03-14 00:00:00 UTC' |     102 |  .648 |
|  [+50 millions rows...]   |         |       |
+---------------------------+---------+-------+


TinyTable
+---------------------------+---------+-------+
|         date_time         |      ID | value |
+---------------------------+---------+-------+
| '2019-03-13 00:00:00 UTC' |     100 |  .555 |
| '2019-03-14 00:00:00 UTC' |     102 |  .666 |
|                           |         |       |
+---------------------------+---------+-------+
```

...

Uses 8 GB...

```
 MERGE BigTable
    USING TinyTable
    ON BigTable.date_time = TinyTable.date_time and BigTable.id = TinyTable.id 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET date_time = TinyTable.date_time, value = TinyTable.value
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT  (date_time, id , value) values (date_time, id , value);
```

Uses 8 GB...

```
update BigTable 
set value = TinyTable.value 
from 
TinyTable where 
BigTable.date_time = TinyTable.date_time 
and 
BigTable.id = TinyTable.id
```

Works as expected (only 12 MB) if I hard-code in a timestamp literal instead of using the value from the join (but not what I'm after)...

```
update BigTable 
set value = TinyTable.value 
from 
TinyTable where 
BigTable.date_time = '2019-03-13 00:00:00 UTC' 
and 
BigTable.id = TinyTable.id
```

I need to run something like this hundreds of times per day. As-is, it's not sustainable cost-wise. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With BigQuery [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) (Beta now), there is a way to reduce the cost.

Basically, a scripting variable is defined to capture the dynamic part of a subquery. Then in subsequent query, scripting variable is used as a filter to prune the partitions to be scanned.

```sql
DECLARE date_filter ARRAY<DATETIME> 
  DEFAULT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT d) FROM TinyTable);

update BigTable 
set value = TinyTable.value 
from 
TinyTable where 
BigTable.date_time in UNNEST(date_filter) --This prunes the partition to be scanned
AND
BigTable.date_time = TinyTable.date_time 
and 
BigTable.id = TinyTable.id;
```

Comment: Haven't tried it, but wouldn't it make sense to have `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT d)` instead of merely `ARRAY_AGG(d)`? There may be repeated partitions in that array.

Comment: Thanks. Incorporated the suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Possible solution 1:**

1. Get all data from certain partition and save it to temporary table
2. Do update/merge statement to temporary table
3. Rewrite partition with temporary table content

For step 3 - you can access certain partitions using `$` decorator: `Dataset.BigTable$20190926`

**Possible solution 2:**

You can schedule python script to run SQL queries like the last one. Google offers [nice library](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html). You can even run them in parallel using `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` or any other threading library.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm current using something like solution 2 with the Java client library. I maintain a table of dates that need to be updated, query that, then dynamically generate a query with the date literals in it. It just seems silly. I thought I was just missing something.
Hadn't thought of Solution 1. It's interesting... gives me some new things to think about.